# Adafruit 2.8 TFT LCD Touchscreen 4 wire pins - unclear instructions

Tags: arduino-uno, pins, adafruit, tft

Warning - Noob question

I am trying to follow the instructions provided by the vendor https://learn.adafruit.com/2-8-tft-touch-shield/touchscreen-paint-example to no avail. Specifically:

> We connect the 4 pins as follows:
>   Y+ is connected to Analog 1
>   Y- is connected to Digital 7
>   X+ is connected to Digital 6
>   X- is connected to Analog 2

My board looks like this

[image: shield board]

and I cannot see any X/Y/+/- labelled pins. I then found the schematic of the board

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_2.8_Inch_TFT_Shield_PCB/blob/master/schem.png

where these pins are labeled but what is the representation of the schematic on the board?

Finally, once I do find the pins, how do I connect them if they are already used? Do I have to use a breadboard?

Edit: After the helpful comments of jsotola, I got a photo:

[image: https://imgur.com/rWXn0nX]

Are these the 4 "pins"? If so, how on earth do I connect these to the arduino?

Comment: I thought the touch panel and the LCD are essentially the same thing because they are embedded to each other.

Comment: I did try the example, the colored boxes showed up fine but no touch input registers.

Comment: @jsotola do you know if I can detach the TFT from the board to inspect the connection of the touch panel? I inherited this arduino / TFT and I do not know the history of its touchscreen. Yes I am using the tftpaint_shield sketch

Comment: TFT touchscreen shield https://imgur.com/a/WSMifOu

Comment: looks like the touch panel has been removed

Comment: Seems really to be as jsotola wrote. The 4 line flat cable, that you marked, was cut. It should go to the touch panel in front of the TFT, but it seems to miss. So no touch detection

Comment: Thanks both - well that is the end then of any touchscreen plans. Will keep it as a screen only

Comment: buy another touch panel and stick it on the LCD .... https://www.instructables.com/id/Touch-Screen-Overlay-with-Arduino/